# Камера двигается за персонажем в игре от первого лица

Tags: c#

Делаю небольшой шутер от первого лица на Unity. При анимации (Idle, Run и тд) персонажа, Main Camera подергивается за его головой. Например, при аницмации покоя, где персонаж слегка поворачивает головой, камера следует за ней. Мне же нужно чтоб она оставалась статичной при любом раскладе и управлять ей мог только сам игрок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скрипты и настройки, связанные с вопросом, оставите в тайне?

Comment: Первый раз задаю вопросы на подобных форумах, как мне показалось тут дело в не скрипте, а возможно в какой то настройке инспектора, о которой я не знаю. Какую именно часть скрипта нужно отправить?

Comment: Ну вы же камеру к голове прицепили как-то, верно?

Comment: Само собой, сделал это через инспектор. Если я отсоединю, то камера будет оставаться на месте и не следовать за персонажем. У меня же вопрос, почему она повторяет движения модели игрока (swat), если прицепил я ее на невидимую сферу (Player)

Comment: добавил фото иерархии